# How to reference another element in same <p:dataTable><p:column> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to open a dialog once the user enters characters in the `<h:inputText>` field and press the "Enter" button.

Next to the `<h:inputText>` there is a `<p:commandLink>` which will open the dialog once the enter button is pressed.

The `<h:inputText>` is inside a `<p:dataTable><p:column>` and for each row I need the same behaviour. The dialog should open based on the row index that I am passing.

```
 <p:dataTable scrollHeight="100" id="resourcetable"
    value="#{myViewITBean.resourcelist}" scrollable="true"
    rowIndexVar="index" var="row">

    <p:column headerText="Del" width="10" style="width:10px">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.deleteFlag}" />
    </p:column>



    <p:column headerText="ATTUID" width="200" style="width:200px">
        <h:panelGroup
            rendered="#{myViewITBean.redercomponent == false}">
            <h:inputText value="#{row.attuid}" id="attuid"
                onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        var columnNumber =  $(this).index();
                    jQuery('#issuesandtasksform\\:resourcetable\\:'+columnNumber+'\\:openpopup').focus().click();" />
            <p:commandLink id="openpopup"
                actionListener="#{myViewITBean.showAttuIdSearchPopUp}"
                update=":showAttuIdSearchPopUp :growl :error">
                <f:attribute name="index" value="_#{index}" />
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="sbox1.gif" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>


        <h:outputLabel value="#{row.attuid}" style="width:200px"
            rendered="#{myViewITBean.redercomponent == true}" />

    </p:column>
```

Check the `<h:inputText onkeydown>`. The jQuery code passes the same index on every row while I need the index of the row that I am selecting. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(this).index()` returns the index of the HTML element relative to its parent, not the row index. You've the row index variable already declared as `rowIndexVar="index"`. Just make use of it.

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) $('#issuesandtasksform\\:resourcetable\\:#{index}\\:openpopup').click()"
```

However, it's probably easier to just grab the next HTML element via `$.next()` as the HTML `<a>` element as generated by `<p:commandLink>` is the next sibling of the HTML `<input>` element as generated by `<h:inputText>`.

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) $(this).next().click()"
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC !!.
As advised, I tried the code <h:inputText value="#{row.attuid}" id="attuid" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) var columnNumber =(this).next().click(); jQuery('#issuesandtasksform\\:resourcetable\\:'+columnNumber+'\\:openpopup').focus().click();" />
Though the dialogue is opening correctly for each row I am still getting the  error in the IE.
Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #issuesandtasksform\:resourcetable\:[object Object]\:openpopup
Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: You seem to be not familiar with JavaScript. I've updated the answer with a bit more concrete example how exactly to implement it.